# Jquery get json object with apostrophe from html element

Tags: php, jquery, json

I create a json object from mysqli query (db class).

class db

```
public function Json() {
    $result = $this->db->mysqli->query
    ("SELECT * FROM table");
    $data = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $data[]= array('id' => "" .$row[0]. "", 'text' => "" .$row[1]. "");
        }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

In my php page I set a data-variable getting the json object from my php class

index.php

```
$db = new db();
<input type="hidden" id="jsonObject" data-json='<?php $db->Json();?>'/>
```

and get the data with jquery in this way

```
<script>
    var data = $.parseJSON($('#jsonObject').attr("data-items"));
</script>
```

This work well, but if I have a php json data with apostrophe like

```
[{"id":"1","text":"I don't know"},{etc..}]
```

I've this error

```
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

I tried to use addslashes function in php when I create the associative array but with no success.

```
$data[]= array('id' => "" .$row[0]. "", 'text' => "" .addslashes($row[1]). "");
```

The json object is displayed correctly in the html source, so I guess it's a problem with jquery.
How can I solve my problem? Thank you

Comment: you have an html injection problem... you're stuffing json text into an html context, and the embedded `'` in the json are breaking your html.  you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape all of those html metacharacters. and this has nothing to do with json itself. you'd get this problem with **ANY** arbitrary text you stuff into html that contains html metachars.

Comment: @MarcB - How and where can I use htmlspecialchars() in my scenario? Thanks

Comment: `data-json='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($db->Json); ?>`. don't just start slapping in random string mangling functions without understanding **WHY** they're necessary. `addslashes()` is a remnent of a useless sql-injection-attack prevention mechanism. all it does is the equivalent of `str_replace($str, "'", "\'")`. html never has, and never will, use backslashes to escape stuff. therefore addslashes() is utterly useless in this case.

Comment: @MarcB - Thank you but unfortunately htmlspecialchars didn't solve my problem